# Web Service MYProblem

Tags: mobile, web, xamarin, service

I add to web reference for my cross platrom to two platform droid and iOS. There tho reference is same. But I don't use to two platform. I add to iOS web reference and droid web reference. I want to my device platform then iOS using to iOS web reference, then android using to droid web reference. How I do this? Can you help me?

[image: Web Reference Droid]
[image: Web Reference Ios]

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep them separate (I would try to add them to PCL) you need to define interface with functions you need to call. Then implement this interface on each platform. If you use XForms you can use Dependency service to resolve that interface, otherwise you need to use third-party IoC or just find the way to pass this interface to your platform specific code.